# How to split a string by repeated characters in PHP?

Tags: php, string, binary

I'm trying to split a string with binary into an array of repeated characters.

For example, an array of `10001101` split with this function would be:

```
    $arr[0] = '1';
    $arr[1] = '000';
    $arr[2] = '11';
    $arr[3] = '0';
    $arr[4] = '1';
```

(I tried to make myself clear, but if you still don't understand, my question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261523/how-to-find-and-split-a-string-by-repeated-characters) one but for PHP, not Python)

Comment: Try using https://github.com/CHH/itertools/blob/master/lib/itertools.php its the same tool ported from python to php from which you have referenced.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) like so:

#### Example:

```
$in = "10001101";
$out = preg_split('/(.)(?!\1|$)\K/', $in);

print_r($out);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 000
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
)
```

The regex:

- `(.)` - match a single character and capture it
- `(?!\1|$)` - look at the next position and match if it's not the same as the one we just found nor the end of the string.
- `\K` - keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match, making this match zero-width.

---

*Note: this does not work in PHP versions prior to 5.6.13 as there was a [bug involving bump-along behavior with \K](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70232).*

---

An alternative regex that works in earlier versions as well is:

```
$out = preg_split('/(?<=(.))(?!\1|$)/', $in);
```

This uses a lookbehind rather that `\K` in order to make the match zero-width.

Comment: Aww darn, I was just a few seconds too slow. Here's mine:
```$arg="10001101";

preg_match_all("@(\w)\\1*@", $arg, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);```

Comment: @paul : Something wrong.. look last element `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 000 [2] => 11 [3] => 01 )`

Comment: @SeanJohnson Works perfectly, thanks. The answer itself did not work, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$s = '10001101';
preg_match_all('/((.)\2*)/',$s,$m);
print_r($m[0]);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 000
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
)
*/
?>
```

Matches repeated character sequences of 1 or more. The regex stores the subject character into the second capture group (`(.)`, stored as `$m[1]`), while the first capture group contains the entire repeat sequence (`((.)\2*)`, stored as `$m[0]`). With preg_match_all, it does this globally over the entire string. This can be applied for *any* string, e.g. `'aabbccddee'`. If you want to limit to just `0` and `1`, then use `[01]` instead of `.` in the second capture group.

Keep in mind $m may be empty, to first check if the result exists, i.e. `isset($m[0])`, before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this. The code id not tested, I wrote it directly in the comment, so it might have some errors, you can adjust it.

```
$chunks = array();
$index = 0;
$chunks[$index] = $arr[0];
for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($arr) - 1; $i++) {
  if( $arr[$i] == $arr[$i-1] ) {
    $chunks[$index] .= $arr[$i];
  } else {
    $index++;
    $chunks[$index] = $arr[$i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother looking for the end-of-string in the pattern.

Most succinctly, capture the first occurring character then allow zero or more repetitions of the captured character, then restart the fullstring match with `\K` so that no characters are lost in the explosions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RYEuY))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('~(.)\1*\K~', '10001101', 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '000',
  2 => '11',
  3 => '0',
  4 => '1',
)
```

---

If you don't care for regular expressions, here is a way of iterating through each character, comparing it to the previous one and conditionally concatenating repeated characters to a reference variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jp9Sk))  ...same result as first snippet

```
$array = [];
$lastChar = null;
foreach (str_split('10001101') as $char) {
    if ($char !== $lastChar) {
        unset($ref);
        $array[] = &$ref;
        $ref = $char;
        $lastChar = $char;
    } else {
        $ref .= $char;
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Comment: @R__ I see that you've been online since I posted my answer.  Is there any chance of you accepting my answer so that researchers can more easily find a refined solution?