# How to count the frequency of characters in a string in a row?

Tags: python, string, list

`input = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'`

output = `[2,1,1,3,1,1,2,3]`

How would count the number of X's and Y's in a string in the order that they are inputted and then put those values in a list?

Comment: you can access chars in a string like items in a list.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: This question is different as it only involves two characters, X and Y, and does not requires keeping track of the number of occurrences.  The OP example allow for more creative solutions  the answer pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
numbers = []
input = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'
split_string = [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(input)]

for i in split_string:
    numbers.append(len(i))
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You could do it in a single pass by replacing the string join with `sum(1 for _ in g)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using a `while` *loop* by iterating the whole *list*.

```
str = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY';
i = 0
output = []
k = 1
while i < len(str) - 1:
   if str[i] == str[i+1]:
      k = k + 1
   else:
      output.append(k)
      k = 1
   i = i + 1
output.append(k)
print(output)
```

Output

```
[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
s = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'
print([len(list(i)) for _, i in groupby(s)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using regex

```py
import re
s = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'
l = [len(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', s)]
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261633/11424673)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try

```
test = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'
count = 1
result_list = list()
prev_char = test[0]
for char in test[1:]:
    if char == prev_char:
        count+=1
        prev_char = char
    else:
        result_list.append(count)
        count=1
        prev_char = char
result_list.append(count)
print(result_list)
```

Output

```
[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any libs it will be like this:

```
string = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'

res = []
current = ''
for char in string:
    if current == char:
        res[-1] += 1
    else:
        res.append(1)
    current = char

print('res', res) # [2,1,1,3,1,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
input1 = 'XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'
output_list = []

count = 1

for index in range(len(input1)-1):
    if input1[index] == input1[index+1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        output_list.append(count)
        count = 1

if input1[-1] == input1[-2]:
    output_list[-1] += 1
else:
    output_list.append(1)
print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is to occurrences and stop if new char come. Code is below.

```
list_of_consec = []
def consec_occur(strr):
    i = 0
    cc = []
    while ( i < len(strr) -1 ):
        count =1
        while strr[i] == strr[i+1]:
            i += 1
            count += 1
            if i + 1 == len(strr):
                break
        cc.append(count)
        i += 1
    return (cc)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(consec_occur('XXYXYYYXYXXYYY'))
```

You can change the code according to your need. If you want list then make cc global and remove return statement and in print statement use cc.